# How to make bot to response the right answer from intent

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using luis.ai and botframework :

My problem is that , when i try to send message ( that are not part of utterance, so unknown input i don't get the message  : $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. Please try again";  ...but every time appear welcome message , from greetings intent.

I don't know why happen this .
Could you please help me ?

Here is my code : MessagController.cs

```
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
 using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

 namespace FirstBotApplication
   {
//[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new AllTheBot());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
   }
 }
```

luis.cs

```
   using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
   using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
   using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
   using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Web;


    namespace FirstBotApplication
      {
   //  [LuisModel("Please Enter Your LUIS Model ID", "Please Enter Your LUIS 
   Subscription Key")]

[Serializable]
[LuisModel("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx")]

public class AllTheBot : LuisDialog<object>
{
   // internal static string results;
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. Please try again";

        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

}









    [LuisIntent("grettings")]
    [LuisIntent("intentfr")]
    public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        //await context.PostAsync
        //("Yes, you can leave your baggage at the Left Baggage counters located in all terminals. This service is available 24 hours daily at:"
        //+ Environment.NewLine + "\n\n Terminal 1" +Environment.NewLine + " - Departure Transit Lounge West, Level 2" + Environment.NewLine + " - Level 3, Public Area"
        //+ Environment.NewLine + "\n\n Terminal 2" +Environment.NewLine + " - Departure Transit Lounge Central, Level 2" + Environment.NewLine + " - Arrival Hall North, Level 1, Public Area"
        //+ Environment.NewLine + "\n\n Terminal 3" + Environment.NewLine + " - Departure Transit Lounge North, Level 2" + Environment.NewLine + " - Departure Transit Lounge North, Level 2"


            await context.PostAsync("Welcome :) ");

            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        // results = "BaggageStorage";    
    }

    [LuisIntent("test")]
    public async Task test(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Do you want to test our bot ? We suggest to type : hi or who are you, help etc..");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("thankyou")]
    public async Task thankyou(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I want to thank you for your time.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }



    [LuisIntent("exit")]
        [LuisIntent("Utilities.Stop")]
    public async Task exit(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Thank you for your time ! You are welcome again here :) ");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your None method is not decorated with the "None" and Empty intents. Update your method so it looks like the following:

```
[LuisIntent("None")]
[LuisIntent("")]
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. Please try again";

    await context.PostAsync(message);

    context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
 }
```

Comment: i try with this ...but it was the same thing :(

Comment: You need to do that and also make sure that you have a None intent in LUIS and that is "trained" accordingly

Comment: after i train the bot...works good :0 thnx to all

Comment: Excellent, please mark the question as answered and upvote (if you can)